# Problem fitting a geeglm regression

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, modeling

I am fitting a model using geeglm in geepack and ran into a problem.

I have a dataset pertaining to oil consumption and fit the below model.

```
geeglm(formula = Consumption~Income + Price + Observation, 
       id=Id, 
       corstr="ar1")
```

but it's output looks like this

```
Coefficients:
  (Intercept)  Income 1,014.99   Income 1,047.31   Income 1,064.58  
      1316992           -453526          -2734582           1626503 
  Income 1,138.72   Income 1,153.81   Income 1,158.30   Income 1,160.69  
     -2879197           -639736            212062           -409109 
  Income 1,182.30   Income 1,249.24   Income 1,294.34   Income 1,300.16  
      1314828          -3177208             -4425           1214973 
  Income 1,316.89   Income 1,336.83   Income 1,339.14   Income 1,407.93  
      -821846          -3295240           -641897           2029621 
  Income 1,430.15   Income 1,432.48   Income 1,433.70   Income 1,441.98  
      -273614           -858012          -3472286           -851193 
  Income 9,187.94   Income 9,224.06   Income 9,313.42   Income 9,720.17  
       621587          -2171161             15996          -4233896 
  Income 964.01              Price       Observation 
     -2469417           -439571            203036
```

Why is it giving me a list of coefficients on every income when I set id=Id?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Income was listed as a factor variable. I needed to simply put `as.numeric()` around it.